# Get dompdf to print iframe content in a PDF?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm using dompdf for a project I'm building, and part of the project requires a report to be generated in a PDF format.

In the HTML version of the report, I have some of the details of the report displayed in an iFrame like this:

```
        <?php foreach ($jobsheets as $jobsheet) { ?>
            <iframe src="http://localhost/modal/customers/<?php echo $company['Company']['id']; ?>/jobs/<?php echo $jobsheet['Jobsheet']['id']; ?>/viewlite/" id="jbif<?php echo $jobsheet['Jobsheet']['id']; ?>" frameborder="0" width="975px" height="272px" scrolling="no" class="<?php echo $jobsheet['Jobsheet']['jobdate']; ?>"></iframe>
        <?php } ?>
```

However, the PDF that is being generated without rendering these iframes. Is there anything I can do to make the dompdf module render them, or will I have to physically include the data without the use of iframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dompdf doesn't support rendering iframes inside a document. You can submit an issue in the tracker.
You'll need to use something else for now.

Comment: Someone mentioned this on the IRC just a few moments ago. I've taken the content out of the iFrame for now.

Answer (score 2):

To display a pdf file generated from dompdf, try to save the file to disk and then call inside the object tag.

PHP

```
try {
    $buffer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();

    $dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();

    $dompdf->setPaper('A4');
    $dompdf->loadHtml($buffer);

    $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    // save the generated PDF to Browser
    file_put_contents('file.pdf', $dompdf->output());
    chmod('file.pdf', 0777);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>FILE PDF</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <div style="width: 740px; margin-left: auto; height: 20%; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <a href="">SEND PDF</a>
    </div>
    <object data="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="margin: 0; width:100%; height: 80%; padding: 0;">
      <embed src="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
    </object>
</body>
```

Comment: I understand people like this answer, because it does indeed work, but, please, think of your server : you're saving all the PDFs directly, and not deleting them afterwards...